# many focused pictures with one focusing in android?

Tags: java, android, camera, focus, autofocus

I'm making an Android application that should take pictures with an interval of one second. The problem is that if you focus the picture before each picture, intervals get too long. Camera.autoFocus() seems to take a little over a second at best and over three seconds at worst, depending on lighting and other things. As far as I know there isn't a way to control focus distance manually in Android and FOCUS_MODE_FIXED doesn't fit my application because I'm taking pictures at a very short distance.

**Is there a way to focus the picture once and then take many pictures with the same focus?**

I have been trying to do it but the focus always disappears after a picture is taken. developer.android.com says:

> "Stopping preview with stopPreview(), or triggering still image
>   capture with takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback,
>   Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback), will not change the
>   the focus position. Applications must call cancelAutoFocus to reset
>   the focus."

Here is how I take pictures now. I removed some unrelevant lines from it. This is all working, but too slow. I have Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini and Android 2.3.4.

```
AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback(){

      public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
                try {
                arg1.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                amountOfPictures++;
                arg1.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
     }
};

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
//write picture to file
//leave cameraActivity when enough pictures written
    }};

//this is run before the first picture
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
            Thread.sleep(500);

        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
```

edit:
It seems that using `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO` solved the problem for now. Means that it's focusing all the time. I wonder how it didn't come to be before. But I think the focusing isn't as good as when using `FOCUS_MODE_AUTO` or `FOCUS_MODE_MACRO`. 
`EDOF` and `CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` are not options because this phone doesn't support them.

I would still be happy if someone knew answer to the original question.